# Передача данных через socket в локальной сети

Tags: python, pyqt5, клиент-сервер, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

Мне надо отправить строку, которою я получаю из *PyQt5* приложения и 
**`отправить на сервер`** в локальной сети.

Но сервер не получает никакой информации, хотя соединение между компьютерами вроде есть. 
Помогите пожалуйста.

---

**Код сервера**:

```
import socket
 
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
 
sock.listen(3)
conn, addr = sock.accept()
 
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        pass
    else:
        data = b"".decode()
        print(data)
        data = ''
 
data = b"".decode()
print(data)
input()
```

---

**Код клиента**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from test import *
import socket
 
sock = socket.socket()
 
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
 
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.otpravit.clicked.connect(self.otpravit_naz)
 
    def mbox(self, body, title='Error'):
        dialog = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, title, body)
        dialog.exec_()
 
    def otpravit_naz(self):
        textboxValue = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()
        textboxValue = b' '
        sock.connect(("192.168.1.45", 9090))
        sock.send(textboxValue)
        sock.close()
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так как вы предоставили не воспроизводимый код клиента, я вам предложу свой пример клиента, где подробно его прокомментировал.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QTcpSocket, QHostAddress
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextBrowser, QTextEdit, QSplitter, QPushButton, \
                            QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout


class Client(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Client, self).__init__()
        self.resize(500, 450)

        # 1. Создайте элемент управления и завершите макет интерфейса.
        # Код макета находится в функции layout_init(). 

        self.browser = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.edit = QTextEdit(self)

        self.splitter = QSplitter(self)
        self.splitter.setOrientation(Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.splitter.setSizes([350, 100])

        self.send_btn = QPushButton('Send', self)
        self.close_btn = QPushButton('Close', self)

        self.h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # 2. Создайте объект QTcpSocket и вызовите метод connectToHost() 
        # для подключения к целевому хосту на указанном порту 
        # (в это время будут выполнены три операции рукопожатия). 
        # Если клиент и сервер успешно соединены, будет подан сигнал connected()

        self.sock = QTcpSocket(self)
        self.sock.connectToHost(QHostAddress.LocalHost, 9090)

        self.layout_init()
        self.signal_init()

    def layout_init(self):
        self.h_layout.addStretch(1)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.close_btn)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.send_btn)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.v_layout.addLayout(self.h_layout)
        self.setLayout(self.v_layout)

    # 3. Выполните операции по подключению сигналов и слотов в функции signal_init(). 
    # Когда пользователь закончит ввод текста в поле для редактирования текста QTextEdit, 
    # нажмите кнопку 'Send', чтобы отправить текст на сервер. 
    # В функции слота write_data_slot() мы сначала получаем текст в поле для редактирования текста, 
    # затем кодируем его и отправляем, используя метод write() 
    # ( нет необходимости записывать адрес назначения и порт, потому что, 
    # он был ранее указан с помощью метода connectToHost() ) 
    # После отправки мы очищаем поле для редактирования текста.

    def signal_init(self):
        self.send_btn.clicked.connect(self.write_data_slot) 

        # 4. Когда пользователь нажимает кнопку закрытия, 
        # вызывается метод close_slot(), чтобы закрыть сокет QTcpSocket, 
        # и закрываем окно.
        self.close_btn.clicked.connect(self.close_slot)        

        # Как упоминалось ранее, когда клиент и сервер успешно подключены, 
        # будет подключен сигнал connected. 
        # Мы подключаем этот сигнал к функции слота connected_slot(). 
        self.sock.connected.connect(self.connected_slot) 

        # Сигнал readyRead испускается, 
        # когда новые данные готовы для чтения. 
        self.sock.readyRead.connect(self.read_data_slot)

    def write_data_slot(self):
        message = self.edit.toPlainText()
        self.browser.append('Client: {}'.format(message))
        datagram = message.encode()  # кодируем
        self.sock.write(datagram)    # отправляем
        self.edit.clear()            # очищаем поле для редактирования текста

    # В этой функции слота мы просто добавляем строку 'Connected! Ready to chat! :)' , 
    # чтобы напомнить пользователям, что они могут общаться.
    def connected_slot(self):
        message = 'Connected! Ready to chat! :)'
        self.browser.append(message)

    # Мы используем метод bytesAvailable(), чтобы определить, есть ли данные, 
    # и если это так, мы вызываем метод read(), чтобы получить данные размера bytesAvailable(). 
    # Затем данные декодируются и отображаются на экране.
    def read_data_slot(self):
        while self.sock.bytesAvailable():
            datagram = self.sock.read(self.sock.bytesAvailable())
            message = datagram.decode()
            self.browser.append('Server: {}'.format(message))

    def close_slot(self):
        self.sock.close()                   # закрыть сокет QTcpSocket
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.sock.close()
        event.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Client()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Вы, конечно, можете проверить его со своим кодом сервера. Я только не понял эту строку в нем `# ?       data = b"".decode()`.

```
import sys
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090)) 

sock.listen(3)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        pass
    else:
        print('client is at', addr , data)

# ?       data = b"".decode()              # ?????????????????
        _data = data.decode()
        print(_data)
        _data = ''

# ?  data = b"".decode()  
print(' ============ The End !')
#input()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Но также предлагаю вам проверить мой сервер, написанный на PyQt, который также прокомментировал.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QTcpServer, QHostAddress
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTextBrowser, QVBoxLayout


class Server(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Server, self).__init__()
        self.resize(500, 450)

        # 1. Создайте элемент управления QTextBrowser и разместите его в макете.
        self.browser = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.v_layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.setLayout(self.v_layout)

        # 2. Создайте объект QTcpServer и вызовите метод listen()
        # для прослушивания указанного адреса и порта. 
        # Возвращает True, если умеет слушать, иначе возвращает False. 
        # Вы можете вызвать метод errorString(), чтобы узнать причину сбоя слушателя;

        self.server = QTcpServer(self)
        if not self.server.listen(QHostAddress.LocalHost, 9090):
            self.browser.append(self.server.errorString())

        # Всякий раз, когда от клиента поступает новый запрос на соединение, 
        # QTcpServer отправляет сигнал newConnection.         
        self.server.newConnection.connect(self.new_socket_slot)

    # В функции слота new_socket_slot(), связанной с этим сигналом, 
    # мы вызываем метод nextPendingConnection(), чтобы получить объект QTcpSocket, 
    # подключенный к клиенту, и получите адрес хоста и порт, 
    # используемый клиентом, через метод peerAddress() и метод peerPort();
    def new_socket_slot(self):
        sock = self.server.nextPendingConnection()

        peer_address = sock.peerAddress().toString()
        peer_port = sock.peerPort()
        news = 'Connected with address {}, port {}'.format(peer_address, str(peer_port))
        self.browser.append(news)

        sock.readyRead.connect(lambda: self.read_data_slot(sock))
        sock.disconnected.connect(lambda: self.disconnected_slot(sock))

    # 3. В функции слота read_data_slot(), подключенной к сигналу readyRead, 
    # мы декодируем данные от клиента. 
    # Затем закодируйте полученные данные и вызовите метод write() для отправки данных клиенту;

    def read_data_slot(self, sock):
        while sock.bytesAvailable():
            datagram = sock.read(sock.bytesAvailable())
            message = datagram.decode()
            self.browser.append(f'Пришли данные от клиента -> {message}')

            # Отправляем данные обратно клиенту
            new_datagram = message.encode()
            sock.write(new_datagram)

    # Когда соединение закрыто, отключается сигнал. 
    # Когда окно клиента закрыто, соединение с сервером будет закрыто, и будет отключен сигнал. 
    # В функции слота disconnected_slot мы показываем на экране адрес хоста и порт, 
    # используемые отключенным клиентом. 
    # Затем вызовите метод close(), чтобы закрыть сокет.

    def disconnected_slot(self, sock):
        peer_address = sock.peerAddress().toString()
        peer_port = sock.peerPort()
        news = 'Disconnected with address {}, port {}'.format(peer_address, str(peer_port))
        self.browser.append(news)

        sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Server()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, очень помогло